# Can no longer obtain form data from HttpServletRequest SpringBoot 2.2, Jersey 2.29

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

We have a SpringBoot application and are using Jersey to audit incoming HTTP requests.

We implemented a Jersey **ContainerRequestFilter** to retrieve the incoming **HttpServletRequest**
and use the HttpServletRequest's **getParameterMap()** method to extract both query and form data and place it in our audit.

This aligns with the javadoc for the getParameterMap():

> "Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For
> HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted
> form data."

And here is the documentation pertaining to the filter:

> https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#filters-and-interceptors

Upon updating SpringBoot, we found that the getParameterMap() ***no longer returned form data***, but still returned query data.

We found that SpringBoot 2.1 is the last version to support our code. In SpringBoot 2.2 the version of Jersey was updated 2.29, but upon reviewing the release notes we don't see anything related to this.

**What changed? What would we need to change to support SpringBoot 2.2 / Jersey 2.29?**

Here is a simplified version of our code:

**JerseyRequestFilter** - our filter

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
...

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class JerseyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
    ...
    
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
        ...
        requestData =  new RequestInterceptorModel(context, httpRequest, resourceInfo);
        ...
    }   
    ...
}
```

**RequestInterceptorModel** - the map is not populating with form data, only query data

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
...

@Data
public class RequestInterceptorModel {

    private Map<String, String[]> parameterMap;
    ...
    
    public RequestInterceptorModel(ContainerRequestContext context, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ResourceInfo resourceInfo) throws AuthorizationException, IOException {
        ...
        setParameterMap(httpRequest.getParameterMap());
        ...
    }
    ...     
}
```

**JerseyConfig** - our config

```
import com.xyz.service.APIService;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
...

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    ...

    public JerseyConfig() {
        this.register(APIService.class);
        ...
        // Access through /<Jersey's servlet path>/application.wadl
        this.register(WadlResource.class);
        this.register(AuthFilter.class);
        this.register(JerseyRequestFilter.class);
        this.register(JerseyResponseFilter.class);
        this.register(ExceptionHandler.class);
        this.register(ClientAbortExceptionWriterInterceptor.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
        this.configureSwagger();
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Full Example**

Here are the steps to recreate with our sample project:

1. download the source from github here:

> ```
>  git clone https://github.com/fei0x/so-jerseyBodyIssue
> ```

2. navigate to the project directory with the pom.xml file
3. run the project with:

> ```
>  mvn -Prun
> ```

4. in a new terminal run the following curl command to test the web service

> ```
>   curl -X POST \
>   http://localhost:8012/api/jerseyBody/ping \
>   -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
>   -d param=Test%20String
> ```

5. in the log you will see the form parameters
6. stop the running project, ctrl-C
7. update the pom's parent version to the newer version of SpringBoot

> ```
> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
> <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
> ```

to

> ```
> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
> <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
> ```

8. run the project again:

> ```
>  mvn -Prun
> ```

9. invoke the curl call again:

> ```
>   curl -X POST \
>   http://localhost:8012/api/jerseyBody/ping \
>   -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
>   -d param=Test%20String
> ```

10. This time the log will be missing the form parameters

Comment: Is it possible to make a [mre] and post it github? Only the bare_minimum_ to reproduce the problem. I'd like to play around with it.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I've updated the question with a sample project and steps to reproduce. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post this answer, even though [@Amir Schnell already posted a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302592/2587435). The reason is that I am not quite sure *why* that solution works. Definitely, I would rather have a solution that just requires adding a property to a property file, as opposed to having to alter code as my solution does. But I am not sure if I am comfortable with a solution that works opposite of how my logic sees it's supposed to work. Here's what I mean. In your current code (SBv 2.1.15), if you make a request, look at the log and you will see a Jersey log

> 2020-12-15 11:43:04.858  WARN 5045 --- [nio-8012-exec-1] o.g.j.s.WebComponent                     : A servlet request to the URI `http://localhost:8012/api/jerseyBody/ping` contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.

This has been a known problem with Jersey and I have seen a few people on here asking why they can't get the parameters from the HttpServletRequest (this message is almost always in their log). In your app though, even though this is logged, you are able to get the parameters. It is only after upgrading your SB version, and then *not* seeing the log, that the parameters are unavailable. So you see why I am confused.

Here is another solution that doesn't require messing with filters. What you can do is use the same method that Jersey uses to get the `@FormParam`s. Just add the following method to your `RequestInterceptorModel` class

```java
private static Map<String, String[]> getFormParameterMap(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    Map<String, String[]> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    ContainerRequest request = (ContainerRequest) context;
    if (MediaTypes.typeEqual(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE, request.getMediaType())) {
        request.bufferEntity();
        Form form = request.readEntity(Form.class);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> multiMap = form.asMap();
        multiMap.forEach((key, list) -> paramMap.put(key, list.toArray(new String[0])));
    }
    return paramMap;
}
```

You don't need the `HttpServletRequest` at all for this. Now you can set your parameter map by calling this method instead

```java
setParameterMap(getFormParameterMap(context));
```

Hopefully someone can explain this baffling case though.

Comment: Yes we are baffled as well. This solution seems to work well without straying from Springs defaults, which we think is preferable. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. The cool thing about this solution is that by default, Jersey converts query string parameters to POST form parameters. So you get the same behavior as when you were working with the HttpServletRequest and you don't need any further modifications. There is also a [property](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#QUERY_PARAMS_AS_FORM_PARAMS_DISABLED) you can set to disable this behavior if you ever needed to.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, after a ton of debugging code and digging through github repos I found the following:

There is a filter, that reads the body inputstream of the request if it is a `POST request`, making it unusable for further usage. This is the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`. This filter, however, puts the content of the body, if it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` into the requests `parameterMap`.

See this github issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21439

This filter was active by default in *spring-boot 2.1.X*.

Since this behavior is unwanted in most cases, a property was created to enable/disable it and with *spring-boot 2.2.X* it was deactivated by default.

Since your code relies on this filter, you can enable it via the following property:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

I tested it locally and it worked for me.

**Edit:**

Here is what makes this solution work:

The [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b3a47c76f8776d9abfdc70aa83c84c252da4426d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java#L85) calls

```java
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletRequest requestToUse = request;

    if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && request.getAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE) == null) {
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(this.methodParam);
    ...
```

`request.getParameter` checks if the parameters have already been parsed and does so, if not the case.
At this time, the request body input stream has not been called yet, so the request figures to parse the body aswell:
[org.apache.catalina.connector.Request#parseParameters](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/0a2ee9b1ba7ded327c2aa2361cccff6a16cdef84/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L3182)

```java
protected void parseParameters() {

    parametersParsed = true;

    Parameters parameters = coyoteRequest.getParameters();
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        ...
        // this is the bit that parses the actual query parameters
        parameters.handleQueryParameters();
            
        // here usingInputStream is false, and so the body is parsed aswell
        if (usingInputStream || usingReader) {
            success = true;
            return;
        }
        ... // the actual body parsing is done here
```

The thing is, that `usingInputStream` in this scenario is false and so the method does not return after parsing query params.
`usingInputStream` is only set to true when the input stream of the request body is retrieved for the first time. That is only done after we fall off the end of the filterChain and servicing the request. The inputStream is called when jersey initializes the `ContainerRequest` in [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent#initContainerRequest](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/82a85a1bffeaf5f78607cf5c0c0d4d4e6ba0457e/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L418)

```java
private void initContainerRequest(
            final ContainerRequest requestContext,
            final HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
            final HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
            final ResponseWriter responseWriter) throws IOException {

    requestContext.setEntityStream(servletRequest.getInputStream());
    ...
```

[Request#getInputStream](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/0a2ee9b1ba7ded327c2aa2361cccff6a16cdef84/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L1040)

```
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    ...
    usingInputStream = true;
    ...
```

Since the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is the only filter to access the parameters, without this filter the parameters are never parsed until we call `request.getParameterMap()` in `RequestInterceptorModel`. But at that time, the inputStream of the request body has already been accessed and so it

Comment: Your solution works, but I'm not quite sure why. Your statement _"This is the OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter. This filter, however, puts the content of the body, if it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded into the requests parameterMap"_, I don't actually see this anywhere in the source code. I'm just trying to understand why this works. Also your statement _"Since your code relies on this filter"_, I'm not too sure about. The app does not need what the filter was made for. Does the HttpServletRequestWrapper reset the stream or something. I'm baflled by this solution.

Comment: Also the issue that you linked to explained how the filter read the inputstream, _"making it unusable for further usage"_, like you said. To resolve the issude, all they did was add a property to disable the filter. There was no code added that put the body into the paramMap as you suggest. So I don't understand why _adding_ the filter works here. Again, your solution works, but I'm banging my head trying to figure out why. Not your problem, just wondering if you have some answers.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha you are completely right, I just assumed, that the OP was relying on this piece of code, if this is not the case, then your answer should be the go to. Also I added some explanation as to why this is happening on my answer, let me know if this still does not clear up any issues

Comment: @AmirSchnell yes, although this does in fact work. We saw Paul's concerns as well, and feel it's better to stick with Spring's defaults where possible. Thank you for your help.